# Slideshow in Html not displaying automatically

Tags: javascript, html

I created a simple picture slideshow for my website but the problem I have is when you first go to the site it shows all the pictures and its not until you click one of the scroll arrows that it goes to a slideshow.   I want it to automatically only show one picture at a time when you first open the website.  Here is the code I have:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<h2>Gallery</h2>
<img class="mySlides" src="assets/images/chickens1.jpg">
<img class="mySlides" src="assets/images/goat1.jpg">
<img class="mySlides" src="assets/images/goat4.jpg">
<img class="mySlides" src="assets/images/goat2.jpg">
<button class="w3-button w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
<button class="w3-button w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(+1)">&#10095;</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) { slideIndex = 1; }
  if (n < 1) { slideIndex = x.length; }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Is your JS loaded in head?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell just from what you've posted, but what I expect is going on is that initially, all 4 images are visible, due to the CSS styling on them.  Then, when a user interacts with the page, your JavaScript gets called, which makes only 1 of them visible.

One thing you might try is to set it up so they are all set to `display:none` to begin with, and on page load, call `showDivs(1)`.